# Unicode category for commas and quotation marks

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I have this helper function that gets rid of control characters in XML text:

```
def remove_control_characters(s): #Remove control characters in XML text
    t = ""
    for ch in s:
        if unicodedata.category(ch)[0] == "C":
            t += " "
        if ch == "," or ch == "\"":
            t += ""
        else:
            t += ch
    return "".join(ch for ch in t if unicodedata.category(ch)[0]!="C")
```

I would like to know whether there is a unicode category for excluding quotation marks and commas.

Comment: This question is incomplete. Generally speaking, you can have question marks and commas in JSON data. I regularly pass XML documents as part of JSON data structures. So here you should show the input to your function, and show how you use the output in such a way that you get invalid JSON.

Comment: Add a sample of  a problem piece of xml and expected output

Comment: The function takes a string, and the output is what I expect it to be. But what I want to know is whether there is a unicode category for commas and quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

In Unicode, control characters general category is 'Cc', even if they have no name.`unicodedata.category()` returns the general category, as you can test for yourself in the python console :

`>>>unicodedata.category(unicode('\00'))
'Cc'`

For commas and quotation marks, the categories are Pi and Pf.
You only test the first character of the returned code in your example, so try instead :

```
 cat = unicodedata.category(ch)
 if cat == "Cc" or cat == "Pi" or cat == "Pf":
```

Comment: This only only works if I use `cat  == "P"`. It seems like Python does not recognize the second subcategory letter.

Comment: Comma is in Punctuation Other category: Po
`002C;COMMA;Po;0;CS;;;;;N;;;;;`

Answer (score 1):

Based on a last Unicode data file here [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt)

Comma and Quotation mark are in Punctuation Other category Po:

```
002C;COMMA;Po;0;CS;;;;;N;;;;;
0022;QUOTATION MARK;Po;0;ON;;;;;N;;;;;
```

So, based on your question, your code should be something like this:

```
o = [c if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Cc' else ' '\
    for c in xml if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Po']

return("".join(o))
```

If you want to find out a category for any other unicode symbol and do not want to deal with the UnicodeData.txt file, you can just print it out with a
`print(c, unicodedata.category(c))`