# XML tag text to string ignoring children tags but including their text

Tags: python, xml, string

I'm parsing XML data that looks like this:

```
<title-group><article-title>Leucine to proline substitution by SNP at position 197 in Caspase-9 gene expression leads to neuroblastoma: a bioinformatics analysis</article-title></title-group>
```

sometimes though there are italic tags within:

```
<title-group><article-title><italic>Interferon regulatory factor 5</italic> genetic variants are associated with cardiovascular disease in patients with rheumatoid arthritis</article-title></title-group>
```

The following python code returns a correctly concatenated title string, but only if the italic tag is not at the start of the title (as in the code above):

```
    #Get titles
    for node in tree.iter('title-group'):
        for subnode in node.iter('article-title'):
            try:
                title = remove_control_characters(subnode.text)
                if len(title) == 0:
                    for subsubnode in node.iter('italic'):
                        italic = subsubnode.text 
                        tail = remove_control_characters(subsubnode.tail)
                        title += italic + tail  
                        title = str(title)  
                        break                       
            except:
                continue
            for subsubnode in node.iter('italic'):
                italic = subsubnode.text 
                tail = remove_control_characters(subsubnode.tail)
                title += italic + tail  
                title = str(title)
```

when the italic tag is at the start of the string, nothing is returned.

Is there a simpler method (not including lxml) to use? Or if you can recommend a change to the Python code, that would be appreciated too. Suggestions welcome and have a nice day.

**EDIT** **[Solved]**

```
#Get titles
    for node in tree.iter('title-group'):
        for subnode in node.iter('article-title'):
            whole = subnode.itertext()
            for parts in whole:
                title += parts
    print(remove_control_characters(title))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `itertext()` method on your `<article-title>` tag and you should be fine.

Comment: Fangs! ^-^ see my solution in the EDIT

Comment: you can even shorten that down by doing this `whole = ' '.join(subnode.itertext()`

Comment: please also have a look at my related [remove_control_characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565552/quotation-marks-in-xml-text-interfering-with-subsequent-json-parsing) function question